# How to create static (hard coded) nested Array data in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to create multilevel dropdown list in Angular. For that I need static data of type below

```
Item1
Item2
    SubItem1
    SubItem2
Item3
Item4
    SubItem14
    SubItem15
Item5
```

In `Typescript`, how can I create this data(hard coded) using array?

I have tried like this

```
public arrayname: string[] = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"];
```

but that is not nested.

Comment: You can use array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array of objects instead of array of string, like

```
interface Item {
    name: string;
    subItems: string[]
}

let dropdown: Item[] = [
{
    name: "Item1", 
    subItems: []
}, 
{
    name: "Item2", 
    subItems: ["SubItem1", "SubItem2"]
}
];
```

Now you can traverse dropdown array to pupulate menu and for each item traverse subItems to populate submenu

Update :

```
interface Item {
    label: string;
    icon: string;
    link?: string;
    items?: Item[]
}

let dropdown = [
{
    label: "Item1", 
    icon: " icon"
}, 
{
    label: "Item2", 
    icon": " icon2", 
    items: [
        {
            label: "subitem", 
            icon: " icon", 
            link: "link", 
        }
    ]
}
];
```

Now by this solution you can nest any no of times

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sub array in a recursive manner:

```
type Item = {
    name: string,
    subArray?: Item[]
}

type Dropdown = Item[];

const dropdownArray: Dropdown = [
    {
        name: "Item1",
    },
    {
        name: "Item2",
        subArray: [
            {
                name: "SubItem1"
            },
            {
                name: "SubItem2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Item3"
    },
    {
        name: "Item4",
        subArray: [
            {
                name: "SubItem14"
            },
            {
                name: "SubItem15"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Item5"
    }
]
```